# IBM/BlueMix iOT dashboard line graph not using database (only works in realtime)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

(See picture)

1. I have successfully connected my iOT device to the BlueMix IoT platform
2. I can see all the events nicely flowing into the dashboard
3. I now enabled the extension in BlueMix IoT to store all data in "Historical Data Storage" (refer to https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-parti/#r_step3)
4. I can see the data correctly being written in the database
5. When I put a line graph on the dashboard in BlueMix IoT it does show a graph but only for the realtime data, it seams its not using the historical data now stored in the database. (refer to https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-partiii/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That works for me.  Can you include your payload?  Maybe something odd in there breaks it. I send in format: ` {"d":{"Speed":0.084}} ` and have my datasource in the line chart looking for d.Speed.

Comment: When I tried to recreate I didn't see historical data either so I have asked our dev team to investigate further.  However, it may be more expedient if you open a support ticket so we can get specific details about your IoT configuration.

Comment: What would be the best way of opening a support ticket?

Comment: This blog walks you through opening support ticket https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/02/get-bluemix-support/  You should also be able to go directly to this link to create the ticket.  https://support.ibmcloud.com  Once you have ticket number, let me know and i'll try to expedite it.

Comment: I created the ticket, but did not get a ticker number just the message "we will be in contact via email soon"...

Comment: @ValerieLampkin ticket number : 5377-13325125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being in contact with IBM using Skype with screen sharing we found the solution.

Turns out that I did not enter an event in the cards config; I only entered a property and for some reason this is ok for realtime data but not for fetching the historical data out of the DB!

As soon as I entered my event (In my case it was 'status' but this should match your MQTT event name specifically) al worked ok!

Answer (score -1):

Can you confirm per the details in the recipe - https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-partiii/, that your Window Size was configured while creating line chart card to display the data for the time period it was gathered in the database?

For example, Data from Last 24 Hours, in this case, window size is 24 Hours and we should see the data from historian only for last 24 Hours not beyond that whether data is in real time / data is stored in historian.

Be sure the window size configured for your chart encompasses the historical time for when you expected to see data.

Comment: I have configured the card as depicted in the attached screenshots (which I believe is what is also shownin the recipe). Since I cannot at the image to this answer I will add it to the org question (please look above). The problem stays the same, only data gathered from the moment the card was open is shown; the historical data in the database is NOT taken into account. So the 24hrs - 10 seconds interval that you can select during card configuration has no effect, and I gelieve this is just the same setting that you can configured on the visualized card itself by using the dropdown.